# Ideia de Event no laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eventos

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em Laravel(php).
Li em vários artigos que "devemos" usar o "EVENTS" para executar ações após a principal ter sido feita, por ex:
-> no controller:
// Faço o cadastro de um usuário
// chama o event(store)

-> no event store, tem um listener pra cada item, ex:
//cadastro no grupo de usuários especificado.
//manda e-mail falando do cadastro.
// ...

**A idéia é realmente esta?**

Pois pensei que poderia ser feito da seguinte forma também:
-> no controller
// chama event store

-> no event store:
//faz o cadastro do usuário
//cadastro no grupo de usuários especificado.
//manda e-mail falando do cadastro.
// ..

Answer (score 0):

Eventos devem ser utilizados para realizar funções quando uma ação ocorre no sistema, o controlador será responsável por, por exemplo, salvar o modelo, então ele dispara um evento que pode se chamar `NovoModeloCriado`, desta forma vários listeners do evento podem realizar as ações, como mandar um email, fazer cálculos estatísticos na base, criar um novo registro em outra tabela relacionado ao contexto do modelo salvo.

Veja a resposta em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/207423/819 para mais detalhes sobre events e eloquenbt observers.