# Laravel 5.3 - Events ou observers?

Tags: php, laravel, design-pattern, event-listener, observer-pattern

Tenho alguns cenários onde posso utilizar observers para disparar uma notification, porém, para mim seria indiferente utilizar observer ou então criar um event, um listener e então utilizar este para disparar uma notification.

Existe diferença de performance entre essas abordagens?

Caso não tenha ficado claro os termos acima, estou me referindo respectivamente as seguintes abordagens:

- Events/Listeners: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/events
- Observer:
  https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#observers

Comment: Se você usou o que está na documentação de maneira a não ter mais classes do que precisa, a primeira linha já diz que `Laravel's events provides a simple observer implementation, allowing you to subscribe and listen ` que o evento é um simples observador, acredito, então que um é variante do outro, não tendo em casa especifico ganho ou perca, talvez outros fatores possam degradar seu desempenho de código, por exempo, um envio de e-mail, com certeza não dá para medir tal desempenho, porque, existem fatores externos. O código em si os dois são a mesma coisa, julgo então, não tem diferença!

Comment: Crie um observador aonde não tem observador, é um idéia básica de desenvolvimento, se você cria um usuário nele tem um observador de criação que pode ser usado para enviar um e-mail dizendo que o usuário foi cadastrado com êxito.

Comment: Compreendi. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento Virgilio

Comment: Parece que events são mais abrangentes que os observers, já que Observers são implementados para Models, ao passo que Events podem ser usado pra qualquer coisa.

Answer (score 2):

Os *observers* dos modelos são ótimos para criar funções específicas às ações realizadas ao modelo em si. Utilizo sempre que preciso manter o código coeso e organizado em relação ao modelo, já que esta determinada ação não impactará outras classes/modelos/módulos do sistema. Um exemplo seria calcular um determinado valor de estatística do modelo que é armazenado no próprio modelo, sempre que este tem determinados campos alterados.

*Events* podem ser utilizados para criar um mecanismo que propicie diferentes áreas do sistema interagirem com ações realizadas em um determinado modelo/módulo. Por exemplo, criar um evento `CompraFinalizada` em um sistema de e-commerce. Este evento pode ser escutado por diferentes módulos do sistema, quando disparado, o módulo de contas a pagar pode gerar os boletos e enviar por email ou já registrar o pagamento recebido, um módulo de CRM pode enviar um email ou SMS ao cliente agradecendo pela compra e já oferecendo uma oferta relacionada, o módulo financeiro pode atualizar a base estatística de análise financeira e assim por diante.

Porém, no exemplo específico que você está colocando, de envio de notificações, eu tenho utilizado uma a mais no controlador e solicito ao modelo que realize a notificação. Por exemplo chamando `$model->notify(new \App\Notifications\ModelCreated($model));`.

Logicamente, realizo esta chamada no controlador quando tenho certeza que é o único ponto onde a notificação pode ou deve ocorrer. Nada impede que a notificação desta forma seja chamada dentro de um observer ou event.

Para saber mais sobre como trabalhar com as notificações:

- [Documentação oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications)
- [Artigo do Matt Stauffer](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/the-new-notification-system-in-laravel-5-3)